# RXJS Buffer Transform but want initial value immediately

Tags: rxjs

According to the [documentation](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-buffer), the buffer transform will wait for a delay before emitting any values.  What I'd like is to get the current value immediately, then only update every X seconds.

I've not been able to achieve this with rxjs yet.  The closest I've come is to bind the observable then use a setTimeout function to rebind after the buffer timeout occurs.  This has a side effect of clearing the current value for those X seconds before emitting the current values.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming by "current value immediately" you mean "first value as soon as it emits", you can buffer on the second element to the last, and merge in the first:

```
// source$: Observable<T>
const pub_source$ = source$.publish();
Observable.merge(
  pub_source$.take(1).map(first => [first]),
  pub_source$.skip(1).buffer(Observable.interval(X))
);
pub_source$.connect();
```

The source needs to be cold so that `take(1)` and `skip(1)` relate to the same element, so we use `publish`. The first element is also wrapped to keep the output type `T[]` consistent.

Comment: Probably should add `.filter(x => x.length)` to handle empty emits

Comment: Your assumption is correct.  I'd like the first value as soon as it emits, then buffer the rest. Though, I'd like to filter out the empty value first. I'm experiencing that the buffer is ignored with this answer.  I've also tried replacing interval with timer as per @RichardMatsen.  I've set my source$ to my rxjs/store select.  I've tried binding what's displayed int he UI to both source$ and pub_source$, but in each case the buffer doesn't really seem to work.

Comment: @MarkDeVerno Could you be more specific as to how the buffer isnt working? Check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o6Lev06g/) to verify if this is the expected behavior. (empty arrays left in to reveal timing)

Comment: @concat The buffer seemed to be ignored is what I meant; updates happened immediately.  Turns out, I was binding incorrectly, as I had my uiBinding set to what was published (and not the observable).  After fixing this up, your solution works as how I intended.  I combined the filter as per RichardMatsen's solution, and needed to add a flatmap afterwards as my observable was an array.  Thank you so much!  edit:  here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jtmzLf2z)

Answer (score 2):

There's an easier way using the zip operator, see lightbulb note in [learnrxjs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/zip.html)

> Combined with interval or timer, zip can be used to time output from another source!

```
// Useful for slow source that emits at around the same rate as interval
// but suffers back-pressure with fast-emitting source

const interval = 1000
const output = Observable.zip(source, Observable.timer(0, interval))
  .map(x => x[0])
```

The Observable.timer 'regulates' the output from source. Note, timer's first parameter sets the delay for the first emit.

Working example: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/RMatsen/pen/jaqroe)

**Footnote**
I just realized this will create back-pressure (build-up of un-emitted values) if you have a lot of events per second, so `buffer` is the better way to go with a fast emitting source.

```
// Buffered version for fast source
const output2 = source.buffer(Observable.timer(0, interval))
  .filter(x => x.length)            // filter out empty buffer emits
  .flatMap(x => Observable.from(x)) // optional, converts array back to single emits
```

Comment: Worth noting that the behaviors of our answers are very different. Both `buffer` and `zip` used in this way will delay the first emission if it's faster than the interval, and using `zip` doesn't really "buffer", rather limiting the emissions to a rate of 1/interval.

Comment: Correct, I noted the same and added a buffered version.

Comment: I do also note that the zip version (IMHO) comes closer to Mark's description, although that could use some clarification - i.e is it acceptable to emit multiple items each interval?

Comment: This buffer version is really close to what I'm looking for.  To clarify (here since I can't edit my answer yet), I'm looking for the first non empty value, then it's acceptable to emit multiple items each interval.  So, in the documentation I linked, I'd like to emit ['a'], then buffer until ['b','c'].  The timer works well enough, but I have to set the initial 0 to some number to wait for the first values to come in (race-condition).